# JSON data to valid data array in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nvd3.js

I need to alter my JSON API from https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=7&period=day&date=last3&format=json&token_auth=anonymous

```
{"2017-12-21":767,"2017-12-22":571,"2017-12-23":31}
```

to a valid array for my charts in NVD3.js as

```
[ { "key" : "Page Visits" , "values" : [ [ 1025409600000 , 767] , [ 1028088000000 , 571] , [ 1030766400000 , 31] }]
```

NOTE: These dates do not match the `JSON` and `Array` but highlight the conversion needed, if anyone can explain to me the date format used in NVD3.js that would be great too.

If helpful, I can add the scripts used to `get` data and display the NVD3 Chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to convert your object to array. Then use `[ { "key" : "Page Visits" , "values" : result }];` to get the required object.

```js
var data = {"2017-12-21":767,"2017-12-22":571,"2017-12-23":31};
var result = Object.keys(data).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data[k]]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but would you know how to apply this to `d3.json('https://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=7&period=day&date=last3&format=json&token_auth=anonymous', function(data) {` can supply full script if needed. Cheers.

Comment: I guess, you have to apply conversion inside the function within your `d3.json`, the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I got that now. My issue was trying to add the `[ { "key" : "Page Visits" , "values" : result }];` and was returning the original JSON. I cannot find much documentation around this sorry. I was adding the `key` name to the `var result` and this broke it. Any chance you could give an example to this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you, Please set up a fiddle.

Comment: That is amazing. Thank you.